# Possible to get file object from byte array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to retrieve file objet from byte array ?

I have the byte array in my hand but what i need is file input object

byte array i got for 1 image is

```
255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,72,0,72,0,0,255,237,1,164,80,104,111,116,111......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not "retrieve" it, but you can generate a new one really easily using the [File constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File):

```js
const buf = new Uint8Array( [ 104, 101, 108, 108, 111 ] ).buffer;
const file = new File( [ buf ], "file.txt" );

file.text().then( console.log );
```

The reason I say you cannot "retrieve" it is that Files (or Blobs since Files are actually Blobs), and ArrayBuffers are two very different ways to represent binary data.
Going from one form to the other always implies that the whole data is copied entirely, and thus why you can't "retrieve" the original, but only create a new copy of it.

Comment: reason why i asked is i need to send file input object (like how you get when you upload image) that same format i need to send backend.. thats why asked this

Comment: Then no need for a File, a Blob would do (File constructor has less browser support). Simply append it to a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) that you would post.

Comment: can you help me with a fiddle. much appreciated. you are telling append the byte array with formdata ?

Comment: Nope, [search the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=send+binary+file+formdata). I only answer the questions that are being asked, I don't work for free.

Comment: agreed..Then no need for a File, a Blob would do (File constructor has less browser support). Simply append it to a FormData that you would post. i have byte array handy , i need to append with formdata -> will that yield file input object ?